# Axes instance argument was not found in a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, scipy

```
def plot(self, fig):
    ax = fig.gca()
```

This plot function is called, when dropping an item on a `Qt` `MatPlotLib` Widget. Finally everything will be updated by `.draw()`. The problem, which occurred is the following:
Calling an external function, that accomplishes plotting, `ax` has to be the *current axis* (fig/axis are not passed as argument(s). Therefore I had to add

```
pyplot.sca(ax)
```

Everything was fine. Just somehow, maybe becaus of updating to python(x,y) 2.7.5.1 (mpl is 1.3.1), I get this error `Axes instance argument was not found in a figure.` It's just in this case, when I want this external function (scipy dendrogram func) to draw on the predefined axis. I tried to follow it

```
[Dbg]>>> fig
<matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x0A119A90>
[Dbg]>>> fig.gca()
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot object at 0x0A119CD0>
```

then stepping into the  subroutine `pyplot.sca(ax)`

```
managers = _pylab_helpers.Gcf.get_all_fig_managers()
for m in managers:
    if ax in m.canvas.figure.axes:
        _pylab_helpers.Gcf.set_active(m)
        m.canvas.figure.sca(ax)
        return
raise ValueError("Axes instance argument was not found in a figure.")
```

The list seems to be empty

```
[Dbg]>>> managers
[]
```

Maybe some of you has an idea, what could be the problem, though remote diagnosis might be difficult. An alternate way of making `dendrogram` plot on the fig/axes I want it to, would be helpful, too.

Please also give a hint on what should be used to update a plot as to `MatplotlibWidget`, `figure` and `axes` have a `draw` method.

**Edit:** Tried to create a MWE. Isn't there anybody experiencing the same error or who can tell me what's the problem here?

```
import sys
from matplotlibwidget import MatplotlibWidget
from matplotlib import pyplot
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow, QApplication

import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hac
import numpy as np

class ApplicationWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.mplwidget = MatplotlibWidget(self, title='Example',
                        xlabel='Observation', ylabel='Distance', hold=True)
        self.mplwidget.setFocus()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mplwidget)

    def plotScree(self, Z, fig):
        ax = fig.gca()
        ax.plot(range(len(Z)), Z[::-1,2])

    def plot(self, Z, fig):
        ax = fig.gca()
        pyplot.sca(ax)
        hac.dendrogram(Z)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = ApplicationWindow()

X = np.random.random(100).reshape(25, 4)
Z = hac.linkage(X)

#win.plotScree(Z, win.mplwidget.figure)
win.plot(Z, win.mplwidget.figure)

win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please post a full example that can reproduce the error.

Comment: @behzad: Where are you referring to exactly?

Comment: @embert sorry, i confused which part was your code

Comment: Just cited the `sca` func from the `pyplot` module. I assume there is smth with the MPLWidget. Apparently its not a native part of `mpl`

Comment: Can anybody reproduce this error with the script? I'd be still interested in an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of `matplotlibwidget` in Python(x,y) appears to be broken.

I believe the file in question is [this](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/source/browse/src/python/matplotlib/QtDesigner_Plugins/matplotlibwidget.py) one. If you change line 67 of that file to read `self.figure = pypolt.figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)` then your code will work as you want. I've included a full copy of the modified code below so you can just copy/paste that into your project and use that matplotlibwidget instead of importing the one from python(x,y)

The problem appears to be that instantiating the Figure object directly, skips over a whole load of figure manager construction, which is why that error was being raised. I suggest you file a bug report with Python(x,y) and link to this post!

Full code with modified line (see repository link above for license)

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QSizePolicy
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as Canvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['font.size'] = 9
from matplotlib import pyplot

class MatplotlibWidget(Canvas):
    """
    MatplotlibWidget inherits PyQt4.QtGui.QWidget
    and matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureCanvasBase

    Options: option_name (default_value)
    -------    
    parent (None): parent widget
    title (''): figure title
    xlabel (''): X-axis label
    ylabel (''): Y-axis label
    xlim (None): X-axis limits ([min, max])
    ylim (None): Y-axis limits ([min, max])
    xscale ('linear'): X-axis scale
    yscale ('linear'): Y-axis scale
    width (4): width in inches
    height (3): height in inches
    dpi (100): resolution in dpi
    hold (False): if False, figure will be cleared each time plot is called

    Widget attributes:
    -----------------
    figure: instance of matplotlib.figure.Figure
    axes: figure axes

    Example:
    -------
    self.widget = MatplotlibWidget(self, yscale='log', hold=True)
    from numpy import linspace
    x = linspace(-10, 10)
    self.widget.axes.plot(x, x**2)
    self.wdiget.axes.plot(x, x**3)
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title='', xlabel='', ylabel='',
                 xlim=None, ylim=None, xscale='linear', yscale='linear',
                 width=4, height=3, dpi=100, hold=False):
        self.figure = pyplot.figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.set_title(title)
        self.axes.set_xlabel(xlabel)
        self.axes.set_ylabel(ylabel)
        if xscale is not None:
            self.axes.set_xscale(xscale)
        if yscale is not None:
            self.axes.set_yscale(yscale)
        if xlim is not None:
            self.axes.set_xlim(*xlim)
        if ylim is not None:
            self.axes.set_ylim(*ylim)
        self.axes.hold(hold)

        Canvas.__init__(self, self.figure)
        self.setParent(parent)

        Canvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        Canvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def sizeHint(self):
        w, h = self.get_width_height()
        return QSize(w, h)

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QSize(10, 10)
```

Comment: This is indeed the file where I took the example from and as you said, the error is gone when the figure is initialized via pyplot. I'll do a report. Am I right concerning the point that `MatplotlibWidget.draw()` is the appropriate way to update the mplwidget including the figure and all axes?

Comment: Yep I think that is right. `Matplotlibwidget` doesn't appear to be very special. It's just a convenience class that creates a `Figure`, some `Axes` and sets some attributes that most people will want. As such, I wouldn't treat it differently to any other matplotlib `Canvas`. The fact that it is so simple if probably the reason it is only in Python(x,y) rather than being part of matplotlib.

Comment: Yea, I suspected that it comes only along with Python(x,y) and not with `matplotlib` itself. That explains, that the issue is rather unknown. Thanks for your effort.